# Image not getting mobile responsive

Tags: html, css, web, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make the image and the text mobile responsive, but unable to do so. Is there anything wrong with the CSS? I'm using Bootstrap 4.
Here's the code:

HTML file

```
<header class="masthead d-flex">
<div class="container text-center my-auto">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-10 mx-auto">

  <img src=" " alt="" class="rounded-circle" width="600" height="400">

  <h3 class="mb-5">
    <h3 style="font-family:courier;">ABC</h3>

  </h3>  
</div></div></div>
<div class="overlay"></div>
```

CSS

```
 .masthead {
 min-height: 30rem;
 position: relative;
 display: table;
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 padding-top: 8rem;
 padding-bottom: 8rem;
 background: linear-gradient(90deg, fade-out($white, 0.9) 0%, fade-out($white, 0.9) 100%);
 background-position: center center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 h1 {
 font-size: 4rem;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
     }
 @media (min-width: 992px) {
 height: 100vh;
  h1 {
  font-size: 5.5rem;
   }
 }
  }
```

Any help will be really appreciated!

Comment: Instead of hard-coding your image dimensions, create a wrapper, set a desired width, add the class `img-fluid` to your image.  https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/images/#responsive-images

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.  You have a couple of issues with your code.

1) your media query is incorrect
2) need to change h1 to h3
3) rem is a fixed font size relative to the default usually 16px.  Use % or vw/vh

```css
.masthead {
 min-height: 30vw;
 position: relative;
 display: table;
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 padding-top: 8vw;
 padding-bottom: 8vw;
 background: linear-gradient(90deg, fade-out($white, 0.9) 0%, fade-out($white, 0.9) 100%);
 background-position: center center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 }
 
 img{
 width:60vw;
 height:40vw;}
 
 h3 {
 font-size: 4vw;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
     }
 @media (min-width: 992px) {
 
  h3 {
  font-size: 5.5vw;
  color:green;
   }
 }
```

```html
<header class="masthead d-flex">
<div class="container text-center my-auto">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-10 mx-auto">

  <img src=" " alt="" class="rounded-circle" >

  <h3 class="mb-5">
    <h3 style="font-family:courier;">ABC</h3>

  </h3>  
</div></div></div>
<div class="overlay"></div>
```